# Wordpress: Tag exclusion function affecting admin pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to fix this myself or find answers so here I am. A tag exclusion function I've stitched together is also preventing custom posts with this tag from showing on its corresponding posts page in admin. How can I tweak the function to allow those custom posts to show up?

```
    function exclude_post_by_tag( $query ) {
        $excluded_tag_ids = array(47);
        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_category() || 
    $query->is_archive() || $query->is_feed() || $query->is_single() && 
    !has_post_format( 'image' ) ) || ( !is_admin() &&
    !$query->is_search() ) ) {
        $query->set('tag__not_in', $excluded_tag_ids);
    } else if ( $query->is_single() ) {
        if ( ( $query->query_vars['p'] ) ) {
            $page= $query->query_vars['p'];
        } else if ( isset( $query->query_vars['name'] ) ) {
            $page_slug = $query->query_vars['name'];
            $post_type = 'post';
            global $wpdb;
            $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $page_slug, $post_type ) );
        }
        if ( $page ) {
            $post_tags = wp_get_post_tags( $page );
            foreach ($excluded_tag_ids as $tag_id ) {
                if ( in_array( $tag_id, $post_tags ) ) {
                    $query->set( 'p', -$tag_id );
                    break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post_by_tag' );
```

The custom post type I'm using is called `data` and the posts use a 'standard' post format.

Thanks so much for reading, I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

At the begin of your function, abort execution by checking if in admin context:

```
function exclude_post_by_tag( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() )
        return;
    // rest of the code here
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post_by_tag' );
```

Comment: Thanks diggy, you just beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the answer. I just needed to change:

`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post_by_tag' );`

to:

```
    if( !is_admin() ){
       add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post_by_tag' );
    }
```

to prevent it affecting the admin pages. Whew!